# Data scraping from LinkedIn—is it okay to publicize it?

Tags: internet, research

I am doing a project using data from LinkedIn. Basically, I am extracting the "workplace" field from people that went to my university. I was told by someone in the research group that LinkedIn prohibits people to publicize any data. Is that true?

Comment: Read LinkedIn's ToS?!

Comment: Ugh. ToS ≠ law. We need to know the jurisdiction and what you mean by "publicize" the data.

Comment: "Linkedin prohibits people to publicize any data" - that would come from the ToS

Comment: Thank you @bdb484 . I am an academic doing research and I am worried about publicizing my finds because of the ToS. When I say publicize, I mean to publish my finds.

Comment: How do you propose to technically obtain such data? Do I need an account to see the data?

Comment: By the API or Python @user6726 - Not exacly.

Comment: The answer depends on whether you are extracting publicly available information that they freely display to the world, versus accessing information pursuant to some agreement.

Comment: @user6726 many thanks for this, I understood it now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### You can’t do this

LinkedIn [ToS](https://www.linkedin.com/legal/user-agreement#dos) prohibit:

> b. Develop, support or use software, devices, scripts, robots or any other means or processes (including crawlers, browser plugins and add-ons or any other technology) to scrape the Services or otherwise copy profiles and other data from the Services;
>
> c. Override any security feature or bypass or circumvent any access controls or use limits of the Service (such as caps on keyword searches or profile views);
>
> d. Copy, use, disclose or distribute any information obtained from the Services, whether directly or through third parties (such as search engines), without the consent of LinkedIn;
>
> e. Disclose information that you do not have the consent to disclose (such as confidential information of others (including your employer));

Since you must have an account to do what you propose, you agreed by contract not to do it.

Comment: Many thanks for this.